# Passing value from Button to setState in array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to created boolean filters in an array.

1. If a button is "Active" (True) it should add the button name to the array ("selected").
2. If the button is "Inactive" (false), it should remove it from the array.

However, only some values end up in set state. I put it in a codepen:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wpxD35Oog

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { x } from './data.js';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movies: x.movies,
    };
  }
  render() {
    const uniqueGenres = []
      .concat(
        ...this.state.movies.map(movies =>
          movies.genres.map(genres => genres.name),
        ),
      )
      .filter((genre, i, _) => _.indexOf(genre) === i);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {uniqueGenres.map(e => <Filter1 key={e} result={e} />)}
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Filter1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      active: true,
      selected: '',
    };
  }
  handleActive = e => {
//     this.setState(previousState => ({
//     selected: [...previousState.selected, e.target.value]
// }));
    console.log('pre-setState', e.target.value);
    const active = !this.state.active;
    const selected = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      active: active,
      selected: selected,
    });
    console.log('status', this.state.active, this.state.selected);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <span>
      <button onClick={this.handleActive} value={this.props.result}>
        {this.props.result} {}<b>
          {this.state.active ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
        </b>

      </button>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would let the parent component (in this case, *App*) take care of managing the active genres. I rewrote part of your code to demonstrate it: https://codesandbox.io/s/JZWp1RQED

Comment: Almost there- thanks! For the sake of passing the value, I really only want the value in `selectedMap` ie console.log(this.state.selectedMap) should just return `{SuperDooper, Movie}` instead of `{SuperDooper: true, Movie: true}`